# Protobuf-net annotation in composite objects

Tags: protobuf-net

Working with  objects in protobuf-net,  I create, with our code generator, simple POCOS with [ProtoContract] - [ProtoMember(..)]. 
What I should do with Composite objects, where  every simple object has its protobuf-annotation ?
e.g

```
    [ProtoContract]
   [ProtoInclude(1, typeof(RetailCustomer)]
    public class Customer
    {
      [ProtoMember(1)]
      public string Name {get;set;}
      [ProtoMember(...)] ..
    }

   [ProtoContract]     
    public class RetailCustomer:Customer
    {

      [ProtoMember(1)]
      public string Demographics {get;set;}
      bool Is Active;
    }

    [ProtoContract]
    public class Order
    {
      [ProtoMember(1)]
      public string Order_No {get;set;}
      [ProtoMember(...)] ..
    }

    How to handle the following ?   
    [ProtoContract]
    public class CustomerOrders
    {
      [ProtoMember(1)]
      public  RetailCustomer customer {get;set;}
      [ProtoMember(2)]
      public  List<Order>  Orders {get;set;}
     [ProtoMember(3)]
      public  int Year   {get;set;}
    }
```

is this correct ?

thank you.

Comment: It all looks correct except that the proto-include should be on the base-type, not the derived type. Is it working?

Comment: I have tried, with simple objects and the protobuf plugin for serviceStack. Then when I tried with  a similar, did not wrok, but I am not sure for the reason,  I will try again, if you think is correct.

Comment: I corrected the proto-include, hope it is correct now.  But in case of code generator,  it is not convienient at all, to be on the base-type.

Comment: partial classes usually make that a breeze. But there are technical reasons why it is on the base type - the same reasons that make it apply to the base type when using XmlInclude (XmlSerializer) or KnownType (DataContractSerializer)

Comment: +1 for partial classes, thx